# Integer to array of bits and back to integer ((multi)-one-hot encoding based on bit values in RGB image)

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, one-hot-encoding

I am working with a data set that is annotated for pixel-wise classification. In the pixel-label images the classes are encoded by RGB values as follows:

> RGB=0b00...1000=0x000008: main text body
>
> RGB=0b00...0100=0x000004: decoration
>
> RGB=0b00...0010=0x000002: comment
>
> RGB=0b00...0001=0x000001: background (out of page)

Ideally, I would directly convert the integers in the blue channel to a 3D numpy array of the bits, slice off the last 4 depth layers. Then for converting back just add one the 0's and convert back to an integer.

The multi-one-hot encoded matrix will be used as a ground truth for a neural network.

Below is the code I have written so far, which is working, but some operations are very slow when I go to larger images and I'm sure it is not making the best use of provided functions by numpy.

Any idea on how to improve this and make it faster?

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np


def int_to_one_hot(x, n_classes):
    s = '{0:0' + str(n_classes) + 'b}'
    return list(map(int, list(s.format(x))))


def label_img_to_one_hot(np_array, nb_classes):
    im_np = np.array(np_array)[:, :, 2].astype(np.int8)

    class_dict = {x: int_to_one_hot(x, nb_classes) for x in np.unique(im_np)}
    
    # create an empty matrix to fill
    one_hot_matrix = np.ndarray(shape=(im_np.shape[0], im_np.shape[1], nb_classes), dtype=np.int8)

    # fill the matrix
    for key, value in class_dict.items():
        ind = np.where(im_np == key)
        for i, j in zip(ind[0], ind[1]):
            one_hot_matrix[i, j, ] = value

    return one_hot_matrix


def one_hot_to_output(matrix):
    # create RGB
    matrix = np.char.mod('%d', matrix)
    zeros = (32 - matrix.shape[2]) * '0'
    B = np.array([[int('{}{}'.format(zeros, ''.join(matrix[i][j])), 2) for j in range(matrix.shape[1])] for i in
              range(matrix.shape[0])])

    RGB = np.dstack((np.zeros(shape=(matrix.shape[0], matrix.shape[1], 2), dtype=np.int8), B))
    return RGB
```

Example use (array is the blue channel of the input RGB image):

```
array = np.array([[[0, 0, 8],
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1]],

   [[0, 0, 8],
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1]],

   [[0, 0, 8],
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1]]])

one_hot = label_img_to_one_hot(array, 4)
out = one_hot_to_output(one_hot)
```

Here is a sample input image. The red channel also has an encoding (which is the only visible one, as the blue channel encodings are in the range of 0-14 and show as black). I am only interested in the encodings in the blue channel though.

[image: Sample image]

Comment: I'd love to help but have no idea what a *"one hot"* array is? Nor why you think a presumably 2-d (or maybe 3-d RGB) image suddenly becomes a 4-d numpy array when you take the bottom 4 bits? What do you hope to get as the outcome of this? How will you use it?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot for more information on what one-hot arrays are (I think it explains it better than I will). The label information is encoded in the bit-array of the blue channel of the RGB image (so a 2D array). Since there will be a one-hot array for each pixel and there are 4 classes, we end up with a 3D numpy array.

Comment: I've also found a small optimization myself, by changing the for loop into a list comprehension. I've just updated the code now.

Comment: Can you provide a sample image please? And also a couple of lines showing how you use your *"one hot"* to do something simple? Thanks.

Comment: I've added a sample image and some more explanations.

Comment: It seems you are not aware of the existence of bitwise operators. Look for bitwise logical AND. All programming languages have it.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Answer**

Thank you for providing an image, if you run that image through my code you will get this which seems to correctly identify the differently classified elements of your image:

[image]

**Original Answer**

I made a sample image as you haven't provided one. The colours in it are as follows:

- red background is rgb(255,0,1)
- blue word *"comment"* is rgb(0,0,130) - note 130=128+2
- green word *"decoration"* is rgb(0,255,4),
- yellow word *"main"* is rgb(255,255,8)

[image]

Now the code I think you want looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Load image and convert to numpy array
im=np.array(Image.open('image.png').convert('RGB'))

# Make masks of main, decoration, comment, background
blue       = im[:,:,2]          # Extract just blue channel
bg         = (blue & 1) > 0
comment    = (blue & 2) > 0
decoration = (blue & 4) > 0
text       = (blue & 8) > 0

# Now edit image using masks
im[bg]         = 0,0,0          # background => black
im[comment]    = 255,255,0      # comments => yellow
im[decoration] = 0,255,255      # decorations => cyan
im[text]       = 255,0,255      # text => magenta

# Save result
Image.fromarray(im).save("result.png")
```

and gives this:

[image]

Comment: I think you somewhat misunderstood how the labels are encoded. They are not directly encoded with the integer value in the channel, but rather in the last four bit values of the numbers in the blue channel. So if there is a 1 in the blue channel the last four bits are (0001), so the class is 4 (background). Or if there is a 6 the last four bits are (0110) and we have a multi-class label here, class 2 and 3 (comment and decoration).

Comment: That’s exactly what my code expects and how it works. Try running your image through my code.